# Glue together pieces of data frame

Tags: r

```
    V1            V2
1   0   58.3354616 15.1455364
2   0   58.3360446 15.1457141
3   0   58.3364476 15.1458118
4   0   58.3368139 15.1459143
5   0   58.3372234 15.1459975
6   0   58.3380975 15.1460381
7   0   58.339002 15.1459897
8   0   58.339663 15.1457799
9   0   58.3402414 15.145495
10  0   58.3411902 15.1447415
11  0   58.3422411 15.1436215
12  0   58.3433313 15.1419505
13  0   58.3464673 15.136081
14  0   58.3508979 15.1277296
113 9   58.3541105 11.9237896
114 9   58.3534139 11.9305822
10  9693    58.3534139 11.9305822
11  9693    58.3533332 11.9313722
14  9693    58.3532568 11.9321196
12  9693    58.353248 11.9322061
```

In the data set above i have a set V2 of coordinates (lat and long) and they belong to certain strings, displayed in V1. I would like to glue to gether those strings that have the same coordinates in the ending and start respectively. For example: The string 9 ends with the same coordinates as the string 9693 starts with, one can say that the string 9698 is the continuation of the string 9. How can I glue them together? The name of the new string does NOT matter.

The above data set is a sample from the one I have. Im looking for a way to glue together all such strings in my data set that consist of >10^6 observations.

Comment: Is there an example of this occurring in your data?

Comment: @JonnyPhelps, the answer (if you hadn't checked) is "no" (`any(duplicated(dat[,c("V2","V3")]))` is false). Carl, two suggestions: (1) please reduce your data, as your question and the concept can easily be reduced to three groups with (say) 4-5 rows per group; (2) when you ask for something to happen based on the condition, your condition really needs to occur in the sample data; so when you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59054227/edit) to reduce and fix the sample data, please make sure your sample data shows at least one instance of "yes" and one of "no".

Comment: @r2evans The data set consist of 1.7m observations, i included a sample. Neverthless the answer to the question remains the same.

Comment: A further complication in your problem here is the premise of *equality* with regards to floating-point numbers. Per [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and everything having to do with floating-point in a digital world (i.e., IEEE-754, it's an issue with every language), strict equality of floating-point numbers is not guaranteed to give you the answer you think you should get. I suggest you need to qualify your question to include *"within some tolerance"*.

Comment: @r2evans I have updated my question. Frankly I dont know what you are talking about regarding floating-point numbers. My numbers are all rational numbers, there are not floating-points.

Comment: I suggest you don't understand how computers deal with non-integer numbers. That's not intended as a "ding", it's meant to say that however rational you believe they are on paper, they are stored and calculated based on IEEE-754. This is meant to be a great approximation of the real numbers, but cannot always provide perfect accuracy. "Good enough" is contextual, and I suspect that in most use-cases it is fine, but `==` and floating-point *will disappoint* (when you need it most). (I speak from experience.)

Comment: But now I see one aspect I was ignoring before: you are checking for sameness based on the string field `V2` which is not numeric. My apologies, I was glossing over that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample dataset that shows your condition:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(rep(1L, 3) , rep(2L, 3) , rep(3L, 3)) ,
  v2 = c(c(1,2,3)   , c(3,4,5)   , c(6,7,8)  ) ,
  v3 = c(c(11,12,13), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18))
)
```

Any tests for *equality* on floating-point numbers is problematic in its base assumption that you can guarantee equality (hint: you cannot, *safely*; see [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and you can search for anything IEEE-754). The best mitigation is to test for *inequality* within tolerance. The question you need to ask yourself is *"how close to a difference of zero is close enough?"*, and only you can answer that in the context of your data and analytic needs. For the sake of this argument, I'll use `1e-9`; if your data is lat/lon, then that equates to about 0.15 meters in the part of the world indicated by that data (if that is really Sweden ... if elsewhere, it might be smaller than 0.15m).

Either way, here's a `dplyr` method for combining consecutive "strings", where we expect 1 and 2 to join and 3 to stay distinct:

```r
library(dplyr)
tol <- 1e-9

dat %>%
  mutate(
    lastv1 = dplyr::lag(v1),
    same = c(FALSE, diff(v2) < tol & diff(v3) < tol)
  ) %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(lastv1 = if_else(any(same), lastv1[1], v1[1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(v1 = lastv1) %>%
  # filter(!same) %>%
  select(-same, -lastv1)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#      v1    v2    v3
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1    11
# 2     1     2    12
# 3     1     3    13
# 4     1     3    13
# 5     1     4    14
# 6     1     5    15
# 7     3     6    16
# 8     3     7    17
# 9     3     8    18
```

I left in a commented-out `filter` there: if you need the duplicated points to be reduced, then uncomment it and you will have a contiguous string.

Another way to approach this would be to calculate the distance between each set of points, and determine your "sameness" based on the distance below a threshold. For instance, `geosphere::distHaversine` or even more accurately `geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid` will give you distance between each pair of points.

---

In lieu of my realization that you are looking solely at comparing strings: (1) I retract the floating-point discussion, since you are side-stepping that; and (2) it changes things slightly, since we aren't using `diff` (or a tolerance).

```r
dat2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
V1            V2
0       58.3354616_15.1455364
0       58.3360446_15.1457141
0       58.3464673_15.136081
0       58.3508979_15.1277296
9       58.3541105_11.9237896
9       58.3534139_11.9305822
9693    58.3534139_11.9305822
9693    58.3533332_11.9313722
9693    58.3532568_11.9321196
9693    58.353248_11.9322061")
dat2$V2 <- gsub("_", " ", dat2$V2)
dat2 %>%
  mutate(
    same = dplyr::lag(V2, default = FALSE) == V2,
    lastV1 = dplyr::lag(V1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(newV1 = if (any(same)) lastV1[1] else V1[1]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(V1 = newV1) %>%
  # filter(!same) %>%
  select(-lastV1, -newV1, -same)
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#       V1 V2                   
#    <int> <chr>                
#  1     0 58.3354616 15.1455364
#  2     0 58.3360446 15.1457141
#  3     0 58.3464673 15.136081 
#  4     0 58.3508979 15.1277296
#  5     9 58.3541105 11.9237896
#  6     9 58.3534139 11.9305822
#  7     9 58.3534139 11.9305822
#  8     9 58.3533332 11.9313722
#  9     9 58.3532568 11.9321196
# 10     9 58.353248 11.9322061
```

Comment: Great code! Few questions, in my tibble the int part shows NA. How do I get rid of that?

Of course my data set is larger than the sample, the code would still work if we had 1000 observations instead of 10 as above?

Comment: Is it `NA` before this code or only after it? It can mean a couple of things, but typically missing data or "it can be any value". What to do with it depends on what you are doing. For instance, sometimes you need to keep it because otherwise you are biasing the analysis. In other cases you can remove it because it is not a "complete observation". So to answer your question, something like `%>% filter(!is.na(V1))` (allows other columns to be `NA`) or `%>% filter(complete.cases(.))` (removes row if any fields are `NA`).